# How can I detect when the camera has finished initialising its exposure?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

#### Background

When I start the camera preview, particularly while indoors, the preview frames and photos taken with `takePicture` are initially dark. Over the next second, the camera's exposure is automatically adjusted until the exposure is optimal. This behaviour also occurs when I open the camera app on my phone.

#### Problem

I'm trying to take a picture as soon as possible once the exposure is right. Preferably I could register a callback to be called when the exposure is good. How can I do this?

#### What I've tried

- Configuring the camera's exposure compensation to be the maximum value. (Didn't help; it still took about a second after the preview started for the camera to get its exposure right.)
- The autofocus APIs, but they didn't work since the camera doesn't support autofocus.
- Hard-coding a delay of one second to wait for the exposure. This is suboptimal because in outdoor daylight, this much time wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Not tried it myself, but what about getting a value from `getExposureCompensation`? If it's still 0 it's likely that no exposure adjustment has yet been performed. (This wouldn't help though if no exposure adjustment is necessary from the defaults, so you'd need another check of some sort for that.) This just comes from perusing the docs, not actual experience, so I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON, yeah; I tried that a while ago, and the `getExposure*` methods return `0` regardless of the exposure (or exposure compensation) the camera is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Legacy camera API

Unfortunately, devices with legacy camera drivers don't seem to support this. So the best option seems to be to start the preview and then wait about a second.

#### `camera2` API

With the `camera2` API, you can check the auto-exposure status by examining the value of `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE`.

#### Example code

First start capturing:

```
// Auto-exposure only seems to start after the first picture has been taken
// And on the Pixel 3 XL, it finishes fastest when you make a lot of captures
captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(request, captureCallback, null);
```

And use this boilerplate code to monitor auto-exposure:

```
private CaptureResult firstResult;

private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

        if (firstResult == null)
            firstResult = result;

        boolean aeAcquired;
        Integer aeState = lastResult.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
        if (aeState == null) {
            // This camera doesn't support monitoring of auto-exposure, so we'll just have to wait a bit and then assume it's adjusted.
            long nanosSinceFirstResult = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP) - firstResult.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP);
            long millisSinceFirstResult = nanosSinceFirstResult / 1000 / 1000;
            aeAcquired = millisSinceFirstResult >= 750;
        } else {
            aeAcquired = aeState == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED || aeState == CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED;
        }

        if (aeAcquired) {
            // Auto-exposure has finished
        }   
    }

};
```